# Is there any option to integrate WhatsApp chat history backup option in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, backup, whatsapp, restore

As we know, WhatsApp is providing back up option by default with iCloud and Google Drive. My question here is, any option or is it possible to provide a backup WhatsApp chat option in my application and once user agreed fetch the WhatsApp chat data and directly upload in to my application server. I meant provide an alternate option to user with my application for the backup and restore WhatsApp data.
Please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you are trying to transfer data between platforms.

Comment: Have you found any Solution?